# How can I remove the gnu logo from emacs?

Tags: windows, emacs, gui

How can I remove the GNU logo from emacs? I am on a Windows system and the green area keeps flickering, which I find distracting.

[image: emacs with gnu logo on a windows system]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fancy-splash-image's value is nil

Documentation:
The image to show in the splash screens, or nil for defaults.

You can customize this variable.
```

You can set the `fancy-splash-image` variable to the image of your choice, or in your case to an empty picture.

You can do away with the entire splash screen by setting `inhibit-splash-screen` to `t`

Comment: How do you find and edit that variable?

Comment: When I start emacs, I do ALT-x it says M-x. I type set-variable<ENTER>. I type inhibit-splash-screen<ENTER> it asks for a value, I do t<ENTER>. Then the logo is still there. I close and open emacs and it's still there.